# Duplicate value ' found in column 'id' in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have one table in my database name is mdl_assigncourses..so in that i have columns as id(primary key),groupid,courseid,status..

so  when i going to add course to the group if it is already exist in the table i want to show error message like 'this course already taken'..and its not storing in table too..

now for me it showing this error..Did you remember to make the first column something unique in your call to get_records? Duplicate value '63' found in column 'id'.but still this record storing in db too...

here is my insert code:

```
if(isset($_POST['assigncourse'])) { 


$courseid = $_POST['courseid'];

$courseid = required_param('courseid', PARAM_TEXT); 
$groupid = required_param('groupid', PARAM_TEXT); 

$insert_record = new stdClass(); 
$insert_record->courseid = $courseid; 
$insert_record->groupid = $_SESSION['groupid']; 
$insert_record->assigned_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
if($result = $DB->insert_record('assigncourses', $insert_record) ) 
{ 
   $_SESSION['successMessage'] = "record created successfully"; 
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); 
}

//$stmt->bindParam("groupid", $_SESSION['groupid'],PDO::PARAM_STR) ;    
  }
```

can any one help me..how to do that..

thanks in advance..

Comment: Is `id` column is a primary key?

Comment: Is your `id` a primary key?

Comment: yes..id is primary key

Comment: add auto increment to the id column

Comment: Duplicate value '63' found in column 'id'.----this 63 is not id value it is courseid

Comment: @RohitAilani it is already in auto increment

Comment: are you need your course id should be unique or course name?

Comment: courseid and groupid should not be same...

Comment: in my case  courseid and groupid is same it is showing error like that..so i want both values should be different..if it is same i want to show error message..

Comment: in my db i already have record for 40-63 ..i try to add again same combo..so by that time it showing errror like that..40 is my groupid and 63 is my courseid

Comment: So before insertion you can check your course and group id same or not...if it s same means show an alert and redirect to adding page...

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that..how to do that..

Comment: first make your primary key as auto increment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155060/discussion-between-mahesh-and-user200).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if(isset($_POST['assigncourse'])) { 

    $groupid=$_SESSION['groupid']
    $courseid = $_POST['courseid'];

    $courseid = required_param('courseid', PARAM_TEXT); 
    $groupid = required_param('groupid', PARAM_TEXT); 

    //$con is your db connection
    $sql=mysqli_query($con," SELECT * FROM mdl_assigncourses WHERE groupid='$groupid' AND courseid='$courseid' ");

    $row=mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if($row>0){

    $insert_record = new stdClass(); 
    $insert_record->courseid = $courseid; 
    $insert_record->groupid = $_SESSION['groupid']; 
    $insert_record->assigned_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
    if($result = $DB->insert_record('assigncourses', $insert_record) ) 
    { 
       $_SESSION['successMessage'] = "record created successfully"; 
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); 
    }

    //$stmt->bindParam("groupid", $_SESSION['groupid'],PDO::PARAM_STR) ;    
      } 

}else{
   echo "<script>alert('groupid and courseid should be unique');window.location.href='form.php';</script>";

}
```